# Tower property of conditional expectations - Application Question

Tags: stochastic-calculus, conditional-expectation

How could I prove the folowing using the tower property of conditional expectations?

$$E\left(E\left[\frac{D(t,T)D(T,S)H}{P(T,S)}|F_T\right]|F_t\right)=E\left(\frac{D(t,T)H}{P(T,S)}E[D(T,S)|F_T]|F_t\right)=$$

given :
$$ t\le T$$
$$ r(s) \,\, is\,a\,stochastic\,process\,(interest\,rate) $$
$$D(t,T)=e^{-\int_t^Tr(s)ds}$$
$$D(t,S)=D(t,T)D(T,S)$$
$$H \,\, is \,\, F_T-measurable$$
$$ P(t,T) =E\left[e^{-\int_t^Tr(s)ds} \right] $$

To be more accurate, I don't particularly understand how one could take $$P(T,S)$$ out from the $$E[*|F_T]$$ expectation. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $P(t,T)$ is constant; $D(t,T)$ is $T$ measurable cause $t<T$ and $H$ is $T$ measurable by hypotesis.

Comment: thank you for the quick reponse. so you mean,  by definition $P(T,S)$ is constant because it is a simple expectation and not conditional?

Comment: Exactly. It is only a number

Comment: great!! thank you very much!!!